# Horizontal center a div with dynamic width using css

Tags: html, css

I've seen a million blog posts about this subject but I cannot find a solution for my specific problem.  My set up is the following:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="position:absolute; max-width:500px; min-width:300px; width:100%"> </div>
```

How can I center the wrapper using CSS. Margin:auto won't work.

Comment: it's `width:100%;`, so what do you expect centering it to do?

Comment: Here's a working jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gWKD5/5/

Answer (score 0):

Its style is `position:absolute`, so you're either going to have to change that like this:

```
style="position:absolute; max-width:500px; min-width:300px; width:100%"
/* changes to: */
style="margin: 0px auto; max-width:500px; min-width:300px; width:50%"
/* width changes so that there's actually room to center */
```

or if you want to keep `position:absolute`, you'll have to manually set the x and y positions with Javascript.

If you mean you want to center the stuff inside it, just add `text-align: center;`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving the wrapper a set width instead of 100% and then setting the margin:auto?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `margin: 0 auto;` not `margin: auto;`. I initially made the same mistake.